# Replicate cURL command in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, http, encoding, monodevelop, roku

I've tried a ton of variations - what I am posting below is a cleaned up version, of what I originally started with.  This is a helper utility Im writing for a Unity-based app.  It's not a game, just a 2d application.

I'm trying to replicate this:

`curl -f -s -S --user $(ROKU_DEV_CREDENTIALS) --anyauth -F "mysubmit=Install" -F "archive=@out/Archive.zip"  http://$(ROKUIP)/plugin_install > /dev/null`

This is what I have so far (see code below) - and it seems like to be "kinda" working, but allowing the auth to go through, and about 108 KB worth of data (wireshark says that the ENTIRE ZIP, about 2.8 MB, is being sent, but the server is saying only about 108 KB was received); I thought maybe this might be an encoding problem (app is on Windows 10 and Server is a embedded linux server [Roku Player]).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PushBuild : MonoBehaviour {

    public RokuDevice SingleDevice;
    public Dictionary<string, RokuDevice> ManyDevice;
    public bool startUpload;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (startUpload)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Upload());

            startUpload = false;
        }
    }

    public void QueueUpPush()
    {
        startUpload = true;
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        string[] substr = null;
        UnityWebRequest www1 = UnityWebRequest.Head("http://10.0.0.232/plugin_install");
        yield return www1.Send();

        if (www1.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www1.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> responseHeaders = www1.GetResponseHeaders();
            string nonce;
            string[] split = { "=", "\"" };
            bool _null = responseHeaders.TryGetValue("WWW-Authenticate", out nonce);

            if (nonce != null)
            {
                substr = nonce.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }
        }

        WWW _file = new WWW("file:///" + "D:\\Workspace\\Roku\\Tempest\\src\\Archive.zip");

        yield return _file;

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        form.AddBinaryData("archive", _file.bytes, "Archive.zip", "application/x-zip-compressed");
        form.AddField("mysubmit", "install");

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://10.0.0.232/plugin_install", form))
        {
            string ha1 = "rokudev:rokudev:0000";
            string ha2 = "POST:/plugin_install";

            string responseDigest = CalculateResponseDigest(ha1, ha2, substr[5], "00000000", "aef3fafadfaedfadf", "auth");

            string authHeaderVal = string.Format("Digest username=\"rokudev\", realm=\"rokudev\", nonce=\"{0}\", uri=\"/plugin_install\", response=\"{1}\", qop=auth, nc=00000000,  cnonce=\"aef3fafadfaedfadf\"", substr[5], responseDigest);

            www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeaderVal);
            www.Send();

            while (www.uploadProgress < 1.0)
            {
                Debug.Log("still uploading..." + www.uploadProgress);
                yield return null;
            }

            Debug.Log(www.uploadedBytes);
            if (www.isError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.data);
            }
        }
    }

    string CalculateResponseDigest(string ha1, string ha2, string serverNonce, string requestCnt, string clientNonce, string qop)
    {
        byte[] inputBytesHA1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ha1);
        byte[] HA1 = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytesHA1);

        StringBuilder _returnValHA1 = new StringBuilder(HA1.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in HA1)
        {
            _returnValHA1.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }

        byte[] inputBytesHA2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ha2);
        byte[] HA2 = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytesHA2);

        StringBuilder _returnValHA2 = new StringBuilder(HA2.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in HA2)
        {
            _returnValHA2.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }

        byte[] inputBytesHA3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}", _returnValHA1, serverNonce, requestCnt, clientNonce, qop, _returnValHA2));
        byte[] HA3 = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytesHA3);

        StringBuilder _returnVal = new StringBuilder(HA3.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in HA3)
        {
            _returnVal.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }

        return _returnVal.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Important Notes:**

1. I've tried loading the ZIP as a `FileStream`. I've tried building a
   raw C# `HttpWebRequest`. I've tried matching the Roku's headers
   **exactly**.
2. I've used both Fiddler and WireShark to monitor the network traffic - as far as I can tell the traffic is **nearly** identical (headers are a bit different which creates different packet offsets).
3. I've even gone as far as to diff the reassembled packets (as per what wireshark is reporting) and they appear to be nearly identical (again mostly header differences).
4. I've used other's peoples implementations for Digest Auth - in the end I've rolled my own.  I'm using a HEAD to the server to get the nonce value, then I use that nonce value to build my next POST which is used in the digest.  From what I can tell, this appears to be working... but I have suspicions that this may be the culprit (when I build the digest auth header the Roku device gives me the HTTP 100 Continue and it appears to accept my digest auth and then my POST request).
5. I've played around with the encodings as well, following the
   advice of other SO recommendations.  I can get different byte upload
   values into the Roku (for instance, as-is, with NO encoding I can
   get about 115700 bytes reported to me, if I do UTF16 I can get about
   270000~ bytes).  From wireshark it appears that the ENTIRE ZIP file
   is being pushed to the Roku.  **My #1 suspicion is that my encodings
   are messed up.**

I have wireshark data, fiddler data, and like 5 different implementations (different from the above example) that I can share.  I can even share the JavaScript used by Roku's embedded WebApplication to show what it's doing (it's a POST using digest auth - kinda straight forward).  Tell me what you are missing - I've been fighting this for 2 weeks now and finally broken down to ask for help!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This question boils down to "how do i do http POST from c#" and "how do i do digest authentication from c#" - if you google this, a few S.O. answers pop readily, follow these.

Encoding has nothing do with it, ZIP is submitted as raw octets.

Here is idea for troubleshooting (divide & conquer) - first teach your app to upload small ZIPs, <100k. Write a trivial BrightScript app (Hello World) and see than your code can upload that successfully. Then focus on bigger sizes - it might be for example that your client tries using chunked-encodding and server does not support it. My point is - start simple and head towards the full case

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation.  I've done both of those suggestions very thoroughly -- you've assumed I haven't because I haven't posted that information, however if you look at my solution above it shows knowledge of digest and knowledge of POST'ing in C# (I didn't include all my research because 2.5 weeks of research would have been too much).  The "Hello World" you've recommended is exactly what I've done, and the very basic Roku app is about 2.5MB, so unfortunately, your general recommendations aren't applicable - but, I honestly thank you all the same for your thoughts.

Comment: @JustinCarroll - i assumed you haven't done it because i cannot read minds. We can only go with the info posted, so better write the info down. Not true that a "very basic Roku app is about 2.5MB", rather it is <15KB; you need not use a game app for testing. Again, go from simpler to complex, first make it work with a small Brightscript app